# Cannot implicitly convert type Android.Net.Uri to System.Uri

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-webview

This piece of code:

```
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { result });
```

results in: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Net.Uri' to 'System.Uri'

in Visual Studio 2022, using Android.Net and Xamarin.

I have attempted to do type conversion, such as:

```
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { (Uri)result });
```

then I get the error: Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'Android.Net.Uri' to 'System.Uri'

I also attempted:

```
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { result as Uri });
```

but, then the error is: Error CS0039 Cannot convert type 'Android.Net.Uri' to 'System.Uri' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

So, I attempted a longer conversion:

```
Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
String urlResult = result.ToString();
Uri sysUrl = new System.Uri(urlResult);
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { sysUrl });
```

but, then the error generated is: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Uri[]' to 'Java.Lang.Object?'

Next, I attempted this:

```
Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
String urlResult = result.ToString();
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(urlResult);
```

which compiles without an error, but then on executing the functionality I get: Java.Lang.ClassCastException Message=java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]

Finally, I attempted this:

```
Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
```

which resulted in: Java.Lang.ClassCastException Message=android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]

The original routine is:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
        mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { result });
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Content;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

namespace myapp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "myapp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static IValueCallback mUploadMessage; 
        public static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1; 
        public static IValueCallback mUMA; 
        public static int FCR = 1; 
        public static IValueCallback mUploadCallbackAboveL; 
        public static int PHOTO_REQUEST = 10023; 
        public static Uri imageUri; 
        public static MainActivity Instance;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            WebView webview = new WebView(this);
            SetContentView(webview);
            webview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            webview.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            webview.Settings.DefaultTextEncodingName = "UTF-8";
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webview.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            webview.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            webview.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webview.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            webview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            webview.SetWebViewClient(new OverWebView(this));
            webview.SetWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient(this));
            webview.LoadUrl("https://mywebapp.net");

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        public class OverWebView : WebViewClient
        {
            // For API level 24 and later
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                view.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
                view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            private MainActivity mainActivity;
            public OverWebView(MainActivity mainActivity)
            {
                this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            }
        }

        public class myWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
        {
            Activity mActivity = null; 
            public myWebChromeClient(Activity activity) 
            { 
                mActivity = activity; 
            }
            public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                MainActivity.mUploadMessage = filePathCallback; 
                PhotoUtils.openFileChooseProcess(mActivity); 
                return true;
            }

        }

        public class PhotoUtils
        {
            private static string TAG = "PhotoUtils";

            public static void openFileChooseProcess(Activity activity)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                i.SetType("image/*");
                activity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "UploadImage"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {
                if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
                Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
                mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of mUploadMessage?

Comment: It is: public static IValueCallback mUploadMessage;

Comment: `OnReceiveValue` expects an `Java.Lang.Object` - can you not just pass `result` directly?  There is not a lot of context here to explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Well, I did attempt: 

Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);

But, that results in: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]

Comment: I am attempting to give xamarin webview for Android the ability to upload files from the user's device.  Should I poste the entire code? (I didn't do that originally as I didn't want to add too much complexity)

Comment: you don't need to post all the code, but enough to illustrate the context and understand which classes are involved would be helpful

Comment: OK, thank you for your help.  I just edited my original post to contain the code from MainActivity.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error messages tell you, your attempts to refer to class `Uri` are being compiled as `System.Uri`. That's not what you need.

You need `Android.Net.Uri`.

Simplest fix is to specify WHICH NAMESPACE you want `Uri` in:

`mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Android.Net.Uri[] { result });`

---

An alternative fix is to make a `using` that declares this:

`using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;`

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!  That's just what the doctor ordered!